# WaitForMultipleObjects - how to properly handle stdin and sockets (FTP client)

Tags: c, sockets, asynchronous, winsock

I am writing a simple C FTP client. I have some problems with receiving data from both FTP (21) and FTP-DATA (passive) sockets. That's my main program loop:

```
    input_handles[0] = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    input_handles[1] = WSACreateEvent();
    input_handles[2] = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    WSAEventSelect(connection->socket, input_handles[1], FD_READ);

    while (1) {
        wait_result = WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(num_in_handles, input_handles, FALSE, INFINITE, FALSE);

        if (wait_result == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
            fgets(input_line, input_len, stdin);
            ftp_cmd(connection, input_line);

            if (_strnicmp(input_line, "QUIT", 4) == 0) {
                WSACloseEvent(input_handles[1]);
                break;
            }
        }

        if(wait_result == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1 || wait_result == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 2) {
            if (WaitForSingleObject(input_handles[1], 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
                ftp_recv(connection, &cmd_output);

                if (cmd_output != NULL) {
                    printf(cmd_output);

                    if (strncmp(cmd_output, "227", 3) == 0) { // 227 - enter passive mode
                        CHECK_ERROR(ftp_passive(connection, cmd_output, &input_handles[2]));
                        num_in_handles = 3;
                    }

                    if(strncmp(cmd_output, "226", 3) == 0) { // 226 - exit passive mode
                        ftp_passive_close(connection, &input_handles[2]);
                        num_in_handles = 2;
                    }

                    SAFE_FREE(cmd_output);
                }
            }

            if(num_in_handles == 3 && WaitForSingleObject(input_handles[2], 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
                ftp_recv_pasv(connection, &cmd_output);

                if (cmd_output != NULL)
                    printf(cmd_output);
                SAFE_FREE(cmd_output);

                // WORKS GOOD WITH THIS UNCOMMENTED
                //ftp_passive_close(connection, &input_handles[2]);
                //num_in_handles = 2;
            }
        }
    }
```

`ftp_passive()` opens a socket to the address given by server and creates WSA event (`input_handles[2]`). `ftp_passive_close()` closes this socket and event.

I have no idea why it works with the commented fragment. When it's commented, my client doesn't receive any more data from any socket.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: So, you show us all this code but you don't think it would be of any importance to show us how `num_in_handles` is declared and how it is initialized?

Comment: It always has value of 2